# Can't authenticate MongoDb on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

When I try to connect to MongoDb running on Kubernetes cluster with `mongo -u admin -p password -authenticationDatabase admin`, I get this error:

```
{"mechanism":"SCRAM-SHA-1","speculative":false,"principalName":"admin","authenticationDatabase":"admin","remote":"192.168.65.3:47486","extraInfo":{},"error":"UserNotFound: Could not find user \"admin\" for db \"admin\""}}
```

Below is the yaml file I'm using to create the MongoDb service.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mongodb-statefulset
spec:
  serviceName: "mongodb-service"
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongodb
          image: mongo
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: "128Mi"
              cpu: "500m"
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          env:
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              value: admin
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              value: password
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data/db
              name: data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: data
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1Gi

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: mongodb
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

I've tried everything and it still doesn't work. I appreciate any help.

Comment: It looks like the user is not found ... , Can you provide    user list stored in admin database?

Comment: I would suggest 2 things, add `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` to env and also verify you are not using an existing PV which already contains previous DB files.

Comment: @Robert Johnson any update on this ? did you manage to resolve this ? please update the satus of question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like, using **mongod** as command

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mongo
  name: mongodb-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - name: "http"
    port: 27017
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    service: mongo
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        service: mongo
      name: mongodb-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - mongod
        - --smallfiles
        image: mongo:latest
        name: mongo
        env:
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
            value: admin
          - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
            value: admin
```